# Event listener for an MQ stops listening once the queue is empty

Tags: java, events, jms, mq

I'm trying to hook up a message listener to an MQ.

```
Queue primaryQueue = session.createQueue("Q1");
MessageConsumer primaryConsumer = session.createConsumer(primaryQueue);
primaryConsumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
                try {
                    Payload payload = (Payload) objectMessage.getObject();
                    System.out.println("Payload\n" + payload);
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
});
```

It's just a simple console app that's connecting to a queue. What happens though is, after i start the application and attach the listener, it reads the current set of messages and just... stops. If i send another message into the queue a couple of seconds later, the listener isn't even up and ready to receive it. I'm working with a Websphere MQ that i'm running locally.

I was kinda expecting the app to like hang on and wait to be triggered again right? The point of hooking up a listener is so that it can react to incoming messages rather than me physically doing a `recieve()` on it.

I'm really new to messaging and queues, so i guess i'm missing something obvious. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your understanding of how the JMS MessageListener should work is correct. When you put a new message to your empty queue, is your application still connected to your queue manager and your MessageConsumer not closed? When you put a new message, check the number of open input handles of the queue the MessageConsumer is consuming from.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. The application stops running once the queue is out of messages. When I put another message into the queue, nothing happens. I don't need to do anything more than set the message listener on the consumer right?

Comment: You need to make sure that there is at least one non-daemon thread running in the application, otherwise the JVM ends. Setting a MessageListener is not enough.

Comment: Okay so if I make it a Web app and put it in a container it'll work you're saying. I did think that it'll need something more solid than an event hook up to keep it alive yeah. Desktop apps more or less stay running with just the event hookups though right? Oh but there's the process which renders things on screen (though I doubt it's continuously using resources when the user is not interacting). Will try it. Thanks.